# How to use PascalCasing on SignalR v2 client-server methods?

Tags: c#, signalr

I've created a simple Hub:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.Hello();
    }
}
```

I want to use in the client:

```
$.connection.myHub.server.Hello();
```

However by default it creates as:

```
$.connection.myHub.server.hello();
```

How can I change it to use PascalCase instead of camelCase? (Preferably automatically for everything)

Comment: A Google search gives me [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/09/10/automatic-camel-casing-of-properties-with-signalr-hubs.aspx), hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @kennyzx I want the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually force the casing of each method using the [HubMethodNameAttribute](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#methodnames).

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("Hello")]
    public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.Hello();
    }
}
```

---

It's not nearly as simple if you want to make this kind of change globally. If you want to do this, it would probably require that you implement your own [IMethodDescriptorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.imethoddescriptorprovider%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

You would likely have to proxy the default [ReflectedMethodDescriptorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.reflectedmethoddescriptorprovider%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and change the names of the returned [MethodDesriptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.methoddescriptor(v=vs.118).aspx) to be PascalCase. If you do this, you could then register your custom `IMethodDescriptorProvider` with [GlobalHost.DependencyResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.idependencyresolver(v=vs.118).aspx).